# Using summary.lm function in rapache

Tags: r, rapache

I have installed [rapache](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/) and I am trying to fit a linear model inside the R script file. I have configured the `RFileHandler` in the http.conf. When I am trying to invoke the summary(model) it is giving me a segment fault error ( i see this in the apache log file). I am guessing that it is trying to print to the console and that is why it is failing.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem with R and `rapache`? I am relatively new to R and summary is doing a lot of things that are not directly exposed as functions so I am hoping I could get it to work

Here is my r script

```
mydata <- read.table("/home/user/test.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
fit <- lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data = mydata)
setContentType("text/html")
cat('<HTML><BODY>')
cat(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared)
cat('</BODY></HTML>\n')
DONE
```

if i replace

```
    cat(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared)
```

with this

```
    cat(coef(fit))
```

it is working!

Thanks
Bharani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. Reading the [discussion](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rkward/+bug/264436) i 
wrongly libRlapck.so to lapack.so. Looks like that was causing 
problems. 
Did a clean install of R again and then modified apache to explicity 
load the libraries then it all worked 
Thanks 
 - Bharani

Answer (score 2):

Did you consider contacting the [**rapache Google Group**](http://groups.google.com/group/rapache) as the [**rapache home page**](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/rapache/index.html) suggests?  You may find more experienced reader there than here.

Comment: Thanks - just posted in the rapache group

Answer (score 1):

I have tested the following example and `cat(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared)`
 works in my (default) setup (latest rapache 1.1.8 and R 2.9.2 under Ubuntu 9.04)

```
ctl <- c(4.17,5.58,5.18,6.11,4.50,4.61,5.17,4.53,5.33,5.14)
trt <- c(4.81,4.17,4.41,3.59,5.87,3.83,6.03,4.89,4.32,4.69)
group <- gl(2,10,20, labels=c("Ctl","Trt"))
weight <- c(ctl, trt)
fit <- lm(weight ~ group - 1) # omitting intercept
setContentType("text/html")
cat('<HTML><BODY>')
cat(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared)
cat('</BODY></HTML>\n')
DONE
```

Comment: Did you have to configure R with lapack? bcos with out that it failed the first time and then i did configure with lapack and it started working - just that it is failing when i call summary

Comment: I have the same version of both R and rapache but on RHE 5.1

Comment: I didn't compile R, just rapache. I'm using the R Ubuntu packages from CRAN (cran.r-project.org/bin/linux/…). BTW, there are also Red Hat packages.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it is not with rapache. It is failing in R itself

```
 *** caught segfault ***
 address (nil), cause 'memory not mapped'

 Traceback:
  1: .Call("La_chol2inv", x, size, PACKAGE = "base")
  2: chol2inv(Qr$qr[p1, p1, drop = FALSE])
  3: summary.lm(fit)
  4: summary(fit)
  5: cat(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared)

 Possible actions:
 1: abort (with core dump, if enabled)
 2: normal R exit
 3: exit R without saving workspace
 4: exit R saving workspace
```

not sure what that means though

-Bharani

Comment: Hmm, curious. The "memory not mapped" error means that your code is reading from or writing to memory that it doesn't own.